# Missing Bars in Chart Director

Tags: charts, chart-director

I am using Chart Director ( http://www.advsofteng.com/index.html ) to display 1 minute HLOC financial data.  The dataset is missing some of the bars, so I add them back with H=L=O=C=arbitrary value.

The result is ( red arrow points to period with missing bars )

[image]

Is there some way to make the missing bars invisible?

( If I just leave them out, then the later bars move towards the left, which ruins the alignment with charts wich do not have missing bars )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set the missing values to 1.7E+308

http://www.advsofteng.com/doc/cdnet.htm#novalue.htm